# ¿Cómo hago para obtener los registros de la semana actual empezando por el día domingo? gestor de bases Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select users_id, areas_id, equipos_id, metas_id, medidas_id, valor1, valor2, 
ROUND((valor1/valor2)*100, 0) as avance, fecha 
from `marcador` 
where `users_id` = '1'
and `medidas_id` = '13'
and WEEKOFYEAR(fecha)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

Esta consulta me arroja los registros de la semana actual, pero desde el día lunes, desaría que empiece desde el domingo.

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza WEEKDAY.

Te regresara el dia de la semana que corresponde.

`SELECT WEEKDAY("2019-03-15")`

0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, 2 = Wednesday, 3 = Thursday, 4 = Friday, 5 = Saturday, 6 = Sunday

Comment: Gracias, utilicé la función WEEK y obtuve el resultado esperado.